# Next Plugin guidance / loop through pages and read static property

Tags: next.js

I'm evaluating next.js for a project. We need to translate the route urls, so for

example.com/about-us becomes example.com/ueber-uns in German

Basically I can acheive this with rewrites and redirects. However it is tedious to set this up manually, so I though about writing a plugin. However I haven't found any docs regarding plugin development or a public API for plugin developers. Does such exist?

(1) add a static property to my pages inside the pages folder

```
const SomePage: React.FC = () => {
  static i18nRoutes = { de: "ueber-uns" }
  return "About us"
}
```

(2) Inside a plugin iterate over all pages, read the static i18nRoutes prop and add rewrite and redirect rules, so if the next project is generated for the German language, example.com/ueber-uns points to example.com/about-us

What I would like to know, besides existing plugin documentation, is how I can achieve the second point?